# ame Already in use in PHP Class

Tags: php

I have a created `db.php` file for all DB configs and db related queries functions in it.

And created `functions.php` file and extended that db class.

And when calling any method from that `functions.php` file getting that error:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class db, because the name is already in
>   use in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\db.php on line 3

**db.php**

```
<?php
class db{

private  $host = 'localhost';
private  $user = 'abc';
private  $pass = 'abc123';
private  $dbname = 'testphase2';
protected static $mycon;

    /*
    This function is to connect with DB
    */

    public function dbconnect()
    {
    if(!isset(self::$mycon))
    {
        self::$mycon = new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->dbname);

    }
    if(self::$mycon ==false)
    {
    return false;
    }
    return self::$mycon;

    }



    /*
    It is used to query the database 
    */
    public function getrows($sql)
{

    $con = $this->dbconnect();
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo "Failed";
    }
    else
    {
        //echo "Connected";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    }
    return $result;
}
/*
    It is used to query and fetch the dataset into array and return from the database 
    */
    public function fetchrows($query)
    {

    $rows = array();
    $result = $this->getrows($query);
    if($result== false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $rows[]= $row;

    }
    return $rows;


    }





    public function db_close(){
        mysqli_close($this->$mycon);
        echo "Connection closed";
    }
}
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    require('db.php');

class functions extends db{

    public $currendata = '';

    public function fetch_current_Record($id)
    {
    $con = new db();
    $show_existingdata = "Select word from dictionary where id=$id";
    $currendata = $con->fetchrows($show_existingdata);
    return $currendata;
    } 

    public function get_language()
    {

        try{
        $con = new db();

        $query = "SELECT language_id from language";
        $result = $con->fetchrows($query);
        return $result;
            }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
    echo "Exception MESSAGE: ".$e->getMessage();    
    }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try `require_once` instead of `require`

Comment: It worked thanks a lot buddy :)